# Finding locations in machine code (gcc/objdump -d)

Tags: c, gcc, objdump, object-code

If you have a particular line of C code in mind to examine in the machine output, how would you locate it in objdump output.  Here is an example

```
if (cond)
   foo;
   bar();
```

and I want to see if bar was inlined as I'd like.
Or would you use some alternative tool instead of objdump?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start objdump using the `-S` option (like `"objdump -Sd a.out"`). It will display the sourcecode intermixxed with the assembler code, if the source-files the code was compiled from are available.

Alternatively, you can use the following way:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    asm("#");
    return a;
}
```

becomes

```
       .file   "a.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ecx
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $0, -8(%ebp)
#APP
# 3 "a.c" 1
        #
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        addl    $16, %esp
        popl    %ecx
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.3.2"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: -S implies -d. You don't need to specify both. :-P

Comment: Oh, right. Tho I like to be verbose. One could wonder whether -D or -d is the default. This makes it dead-brain safe :p

Answer (score 2):

You debugger should also let you see source code and matching assembly if you compiled with debug symbols. This is gcc option -g and gdb disass command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling with gcc, you can use -S to generate an assembly file directly.  This file usually has some useful information in it, including function names and sometimes line numbers for code (depending on the compile options you use).

Comment: You can also use -save-temps to both compile and generate the assembly file (and others) as a byproduct.

Answer (score 0):

Function calls are detected in the assembly by the common function prolog.

With i386 it is

```
  55      push %ebp
  89 e5   mov %esp, %ebp
  ...
  c9      leave # optional
  c3      ret
```

with amd64/x86_64 is is similar (just the quad prefix `48`):

```
  55                    push   %rbp
  48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
  ..
  c9                    leaveq # optional
  c3                    retq
```

So when you detect that inside your `objdump -S bla.o` 
or 
`gcc bla.c -g -fsave-temps -fverbose-asm` output of your main function 
and for bar also, bar is not inlined. Also when main has a call or jump 
to bar it is not inlined.

In your case you could see if bar has local vars, which needs room on 
the local stack. If bar is inlined the stack adjust (e.g. `sub $0x8,%esp`) 
is done right after the main prolog, main could access that var. 
If not it is private to bar.